# Detect IE11 browser and show cms block modal with phtml script tag

Tags: php, javascript, requirejs, script, modal-popup

I have a modal that pops up when the site detects it's on IE11. The modal is in a cms block so that the client can edit it. I have created a reference container with a custom phtml and put the script in there. But it's not working! Is this because the script is in a phtml file? and if so can I call a block using php in a js file?  Please note that I'm trying to detect chrome in this example as I'm on a mac.

`<script type="text/javascript"> document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ if (!navigator.userAgent.includes('Chrome')) { <?php echo $this->getLayout() ->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block') ->setBlockId('dontuseie') ->toHtml(); ?> }   });     </script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripts in CMS Blocks sounds like something that Magento would block.

If it is just the content of the "dontuseie" block that needs to be admin-editable, you could:

1. Render that block in a hidden div.
2. Show the div where applicable using a script included by the supported Magento methods (source code or Scripts and Style Sheets).

Comment: Thank you for the workaround, that worked a treat.